How to get and set nested data in Newtonsoft.Json.JObject
I work in C#, and use Newtonsoft.Json objects a lot, as I am interacting with client-side javascript and json.
I often have a complex json stricture representing options on something in a C# class. I usually wrap most of the items in C# properties to make them easier to use from C# (and to gain compile time type checking).
I would like to make a property which sets multipage.pages to an array of strings. The 'multipage' element may or may not already exist.
I wondered if Newtonsoft.Json provides an easy way to ensure all the elements in a multi-element tree exist when creating a new one? I tried
JObject j = new JObject();
j["multipage.keepSave"] = true;
Console.WriteLine(j.ToString());

but the output was (understandably - json has no rules about what can be in a name)
{
  "multipage,keepSave": true
}

The alternative seems to be a bit tedious:
void Main() {
    Form f = new Form();
    Console.WriteLine(f.KeepSave);
    f.KeepSave = true;
    Console.WriteLine(f.KeepSave);
    f.KeepSave = false;
    Console.WriteLine(f.KeepSave);
    Console.WriteLine(f.Options.ToString());
}

public class Form {
    public JObject Options = new JObject();
    public bool KeepSave
    {
        get
        {
            JToken t = Options["multipage"];
            if(t == null)
                return false;
            return (bool)t["keepsave"]; 
        }
        set {
            JToken t = Options["multipage"];
            if(t == null)
                Options["multipage"] = t = new JObject();
            t["keepsave"] = value;
        }
    }
}

I suppose I could create my own generic code:
void Main() {
    Form f = new Form();
    Console.WriteLine(f.KeepSave);
    f.KeepSave = true;
    Console.WriteLine(f.KeepSave);
    f.KeepSave = false;
    Console.WriteLine(f.KeepSave);
    Console.WriteLine(f.Options.ToString());
}

static public void SetJObject(JToken o, string path, object value) {
    List<string> p = path.Split('.').ToList();
    for(int i = 0; i < p.Count - 1; i++) {
    string name = p[i];
        JToken j = o[name];
        if(j == null)
            o[name] = j = new JObject();
        o = j;
    }
    o[p[p.Count - 1]] = JToken.FromObject(value);
}

public class Form {
    public JObject Options = new JObject();
    public bool KeepSave
    {
        get
        {
            JToken t = Options.SelectToken("multipage.keepsave");
            return t == null ? false : (bool)t; 
        }
        set {
            SetJObject(Options, "multipage.keepsave", value);
        }
    }
}

Suggestions for improvement welcome!

"multipage.keepSave" is a JSONPath expression.  To get a value via JSONPath use SelectToken(), see How do I get a nested value from JSON using Json.NET's JObject?.  Chaining together null conditional operators is also an option, see Reading JSON By JSON tag.

As for populating a JObject from a JSONPath expression, there's nothing built in.  But you could check to see whether this answer by Danny Su to How to unflatten flattened json in C# does what you want.

Do those questions answer yours also?

Thanks for the comments - the other answers are interesting and useful reading.
